# The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker, devops

[image]

when I'm running docker build command its shows this error :

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1

can anyone help me with that

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], at least including the Dockerfile, and parts of your application's build environment if they're necessary?  Is there any more of the error message than the "returned a non-zero code" message?  You included an image as part of the question; how is it that file used as part of the build sequence?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your screenshot is so small that it's impossible to read the text. In general, posting text is much preferred over screenshots as it's much easier for someone to copy it to their own computer to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dotnet restore should be run in a project directory
here you are stating WORKDIR /app , but copying in a strange directory named /path/to/dir/in/image
running dotnet restore and then again copying to /app

it seems that you are using some kind of manual and author is forcing you to edit "/path/to/dir/in/image" with your path, but you've just copy-pasted the string

try to

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

Comment: i have tried with this but after that i got issue in Run dotnet restore

Comment: If you want further assistance, you can post your error here.